# Return a specific column from a many-many relationship using php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, many-to-many, transform

In my database I have two models, User and Role defined as many-many relationship, I'm trying to write a code in laravel that takes the id from the roles table and gets all the user fullnames from the users table.

I have defined a route that looks like this :

```
Route::get('roleUser/{role}', 'RoleController@RoleNames');
```

in which i pass the role name with it, as you see above

In my RoleController, I defined the method roleNames to do the job

```
public function RoleNames($role)
{


    $idrole = Role::where('name', '=', $role)->first()->id;
    //$iduser = DB::table('assigned_roles')->where('role_id', '=', $idrole)->first()->id;
    $iduser = DB::table('assigned_roles')->where('role_id', '=', $idrole)->get(array('id'));

    $usersUnderRole = array();
    foreach ($iduser as $idusers) {

        $usersUnderRole = array_add($usersUnderRole, $idrole, $idusers);

         $full_name = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $idusers)->get()->full_name;
     }
         return $this->respond([
             'result' => $this -> roleTransformer->transform($full_name)

         ]);
}
```

This code is meant to take the `role_id` from the `roles` table and gets the appropriate `user_ids` by the pivot table assigned_roles, puts them in an array and fetches the correspondent `full_names`, but it says this error:

> - Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Any advice on how to get it to work?

Comment: `$full_name = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $idusers)->get()->full_name;` this part is strange, query builder `get` will return with a collection, not with a single row. Don't you mean `...->first()->full_name` ?

Comment: I'm trying to get all the usernames that are related to the specified role, not only the first user  @lamzozo

Comment: Eloquent is not playing? Are stick you stick to query builder? It could be done with a few lines with eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the solution @lamzazo provided, there is another way to go with the answer :

```
        $role2 = Role::where('name', '=', $role)->first();

        $idrole = Role::where('name', '=', $role)->first()->id;
        //$iduser = DB::table('assigned_roles')->where('role_id', '=', $idrole);
        $user = DB::table('assigned_roles')->where('role_id', '=', $idrole)->get();
       // $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $iduser);


        // return $this->respond($iduser[0]->user_id);


       $userArray = array();

        $i=0;

        foreach ($user as $users) {
            $iduser= $users->user_id;
            $allusers = User::where('id', '=', $iduser)->get(array('id', 'full_name'));
            $userArray = array_add($userArray, $i . '', $allusers);
            $i++;

        }



       return $this->respond([
              'result' => $this -> roleTransformer->testTransform($role2, $userArray)

       ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the users who belong to the given role:

```
$role_id = 3;

$result = DB::table('role_user')
  ->select('users.full_name')
  ->where('role_user.role_id', $role_id)
  ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
  ->get();

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: thank you very much, this was actually helpful @lamzozo

Answer (score 0):

$full_names = DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $idusers)->lists('users.full_name');